# Как программно работать с двумя сим-картами на Android?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Пишу ПО для бэкапа входящих и исходящих вызовов и смс.
Но как бэкапить с пометкой на какую симку что-то пришло и с какой ушло?

Почти все телефоны, которые поддерживают две симки, созданы на платформах MTK и samsung duos.

Но я не смог найти ни готовых библиотек, ни java классов, которые могли бы мне в этом помочь.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. "Которые могли бы мне помочь" - помочь в чем именно? В сохраненнии, в определении, в перехвате сообщений?

Comment: В сохранении и определении какая смс была принята с пометной SIM-1 или SIM-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А их просто не существует(библиотек).
Официально Андроид поддерживает несколько сим-карт только с версии 5.1
А это значит, что все телефоны, что были до него работают на допиленных производителями прошивках. И, как можно догадаться, нет никакого единого стандарта, а тем более - API для работы с несколькими сим-картами. Так что если вы хотите сделать так, чтобы работало на всех телефонах, вам придется декомпилировать прошивку каждой модели телефона с 2+ сим картами, смотреть, как именно организована работа с ними, и создавать решение отдельно для каждого телефона.

Comment: Да мне по большей части нужны только MTK, так как samsung duos остался в прошлом.
У них нашел коечто http://labs.mediatek.com/site/global/developer_tools/mediatek_android/api_references/mediatek-sdk3/reference/com/mediatek/telephony/package-summary.gsp
Думаю что это подойдет для всех устройств на платформе MTK

Comment: Да, MTK недавно открыли API для работы с несколькими SIM картатами на своих устройствах. Пододйет.

Comment: @4BAL0V, оформите коммент как ответ. Думаю, не помешает

Answer (score 1):

Для телефонов на базе MTK есть открытое API - http://labs.mediatek.com/site/global/developer_tools/mediatek_android/api_references/mediatek-sdk3/reference/com/mediatek/telephony/package-summary.gsp